How to change "Continue shopping" link on the Shopify Thank you page?
I'm trying to change link for the Continue shopping button on the Thank you page (Dawn theme), which is displayed after the checkout.
I didn't find related settings in shopify admin panel. Editing theme code (replacing routes.all_products_collection_url) works only for the cart page, there is no smth like 'thankyou.liquid'. Some articles\answers suggest to add script but this method seems deprecated.

To change the URL of continue shopping button, you need to do some changes in the theme code.
In the theme code editor, find the file named: main-cart-items.liquid and search for search for cart__empty-text
Screen shot for reference

Now you need to change the href of a tag to {{ routes.root_url }}
Screen shot for reference

Hope this might be helpful what you are looking for. Try if this works.

I think this process works on cart page, not on after checkout page.
